# How can I create users with only remote ftp access on Linux server?

Tags: users, ftp

I'm running a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server and I want to create users who can only access the server from FTP.

What I did so far is:

- Install `vsftpd`
- Create new user with default login shell set to `/bin/false`

The normal users on the server are all able to access their home folder through ftp but the users to whom remote shell access is removed by setting it to `/bin/false` are not able to log by ftp either.

I don't understand how the shell access affects the `vsftpd` server? How could I enable the ftp access without re-enabling shell?

Update:
I found [this reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-prevent-normal-users-from-logging-into-system.html) that states that I should use `/sbin/nologin` (seems to be `/usr/sbin/nologin` in Ubuntu) and that it should not affect ftp access but it does not work in my case.

Comment: May be try setting to /bin/true

Comment: I've never used vsftpd but [I found solution](http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/) that do what you need. I don't know if it is best solution (I think it should work, but maybe there is something better).

Comment: Just tried /bin/true and it does not work.

Comment: Thanks @pbm but it is not exactly what I'm looking for because I'd prefer to use real users.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if it is good practice to answer my own question but I found a simple solution that enables ftp login.

I needed to add the line

> /usr/sbin/nologin

to the file /etc/shells. Right after this modification the ftp server started to accept login from users to whom the shell is set /usr/sbin/nologin. So they cannot login through ssh but it works with ftp exactly as I wanted.

Thanks for your helpful comments.

Comment: I read somewhere a few days ago that this opens security vulnerability. Any experts out there that can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set users shell back to `/bin/false` (or some other invalid shell) then set `/bin/false` in `/etc/shells`.

I see a **major** security issue with setting `/usr/sbin/nologin` into `/etc/shells`.  You are giving FTP (and perhaps other) access to all daemons and logins that have `/usr/sbin/nologin` as their shell.

Comment: How, exactly? nologin exists to allow, well, nologin - with an optional customized message in `/etc/nologin.txt` so the ftp user could know it's ftp only or some such.

Comment: vsftpd is the one protecting from unauthorized access by having it's own access lists.